# Visual Studio 2010 snippets not working

Tags: c#, settings, code-snippets

For some reason the automatic insertion of code snippets doesn't work in my Visual Studio 2010. I want to do exactly this: 
http://www.onesoft.dk/post/Using-the-switch-code-snippet-with-an-enum.aspx

It used to work fine but now it doesn't work anymore. It also doesn't work on for example foreach. Has anybody a idea why it's not working?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have ReSharper installed recently by any chance?

If so try <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and they all list.

You can also disable Resharper messing with your Intellisense from Resharper settings under 
Resharper Options > Environment > IntelliSense > (Visual Studio)